# 5-digit binary code lock

Tags: circuit-design, homework, binary

I am trying to design a two-button, 5-digit binary code entry lock.

For simplicity, I have designed below a 4-digit lock, without a reset. I wanted the LED to turn off once the pin "1101" was entered.

However, I found that the LED still stays on. I am not even sure if this circuit would work. Any tips would be appreciated.

This is meant to be an exercise in state machines, so we can't use microcontrollers or Arduino.

I am using a CD4012BE Dual D Flip Flop, a 74LS14N Hex Schmitt Trigger Inverter and a 2N2222A NPN Transistor.
*S* should be connected to a reset button.
I can't use a Johnson counter unfortunately :(
[image]

Comment: This is the sort of problem that, if you're doing it with anything other than a microcontroller, you're almost certainly doing it wrong.

Comment: how can anyone have suggestions when you did not explain how the lock is supposed to work?

Comment: If you tagged this **only** with [tag:homework] instead of [tag:security], I could see how this would be kind of an exercise in simple finite state machines. However, since security is involved: that's only 32 possible combinations. Even if you block the lock after 3 wrong attempts, a thief would have a nearly 10% chance of getting the combination right on the first try. So, instead of a 5-element binary key, a 3-element quarternary key would already be twice as secure. But handling such an entry in discrete parts gets very cumbersome, very quickly. Very clearly a job for a microcontroller.

Comment: Yeah it's basically an exercise for finite state machines. I was planning on using 3 dual d flip flops to create the 5 digit code. The circuit above limits it since you can't use the same button (digit) twice.

Comment: @Johnnydepp Are the two buttons **0** and **1**? (I'm not sure if you are talking about a 5 bit binary code or a 5-digit BCD.) And how to you reset it if you screw up and want to start over? And how to you create the original lock code? And why do I see so many buttons on the left? Does that mean a decimal keypad and this isn't a binary code lock?

Comment: Yes it's 0 and 1.

Comment: The design above was just a potential idea. I haven't thought about a reset yet, I was just going to turn the system on and off to restart it. The original lock code would essentially be wired according the order the flip flop are placed, and each flipflop would be wired to 1 of the 2 buttons

Comment: I will post a better circuit diagram soon

Comment: @Johnnydepp You may require debouncing for the switches. For a practical system, anyway.

Comment: @erikr I can't use a Johnson counter unfortunately  :(

Comment: Would I still be able to just replace the Johnson counter with the flip flops?

Comment: For entering the "lock code" one button is enough - you can do clever things with pulse widths, feeding the code into a serial-to-parallel shift register. A short button-press can yield a **zero**, while a long button-press can yield a **one** by using RC time-constants. Or use one button for shift-register **clk** and the other button for shift-register **data**. As @Hearth suggests, an ideal microcontroller project.

Comment: @Johnnydepp Just pre-load (on power-up) a circular shift register with a single "1" and that's the same as the 4022.

Comment: @glen_geek yeah wish we could use microcontrollers.

Comment: The transistor and LED after R1 appear to be reversed, and no limiting resistor for the LED. You could just drive the LED directly from the flip-flop.

Comment: alright so i have taken out the transistor. So the output of the flip flop goes into R1 to the positive terminal of LED, and the negative terminal connected to ground.

Comment: It still doesnt seem to work

Comment: Why are left the S inputs "on air"?

Comment: You can only push 0 into the register?

Comment: Oh my bad, S should be connected to a reset button

Comment: I'm still very much unsure why this wouldn't work. Would someone please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of a design I think you can make work.

First notice that the arrangement of flip-flops (Q goes to the next D) resembles a Johnson counter. So it might be easier to use a decoded Johnson counter like a CD4017 or CD4022. Indeed, this design:

https://www.electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/electronic-combination-lock

utilizes a CD4022.

To get around the two switch limit you first need to debounce them using a edge-detector circuit like found in this article:

http://www.n5dux.com/ham/files/pdf/Working%20With%20Monostable%20Multivibrators.pdf

Basically, when you press an input you want to generate a single pulse of some short duration. In order to generate another pulse you need to release the switch and press it again.

Now consider the following modification the above CD4022 circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJGMja.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A-pulse is the debounced signal from one of the inputs (the "A" key) and B-pulse is the same for the other input (the "B" key).

Because only one output of the 4022 is active at a time, A and B will be logical inverses of each other.

MUX1 handles detection of the correct key press. Suppose Out0 is the currently active output and it is connected to A. In order to advance the counter the "A" key needs to be pressed. If it was connected to B the "B" key would need to be pressed.

MUX2 will reset the circuit if the wrong key is pressed.

There are still a lot of timing details to work out.

Comment: Johnny depp: [`I can't use a Johnson counter unfortunately :(`](/q/640243/5-digit-binary-code-lock#comment1696844_640243) And to spell out what's missing from the circuit in the question: a reset/fault state when a false key is pressed.